# PHP call python command from web XAMPP Server

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, xampp

I'm using XAMPP Server and PHP on my Web Server running on Windows Server 2012.

And now I have raspberry pi that need to run this below command.

```
sudo python /home/pi/open.py
```

open.py is on /home/pi/.

I tried to run it using shell cmd and it worked.

But now my question, how can I call `sudo python /home/pi/open.py` from web (the web server is on windows)?

assume raspberry pi IP Address: 192.168.1.145.

What I've tried is:

```
$piaddress = "192.168.1.145";
shell_exec("sudo python" .$piaddress."/home/pi/open.py");
```

But it's not working.

Comment: It's unlikely that the user running your web server will have sufficient permissions to run `sudo` commands

Comment: is it possible to grant the access?

Comment: I'd argue that the raspberry pi on its own can handle your use case with much less complexity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Transfer the python script to the server you want to run the script.
2. Setup key based SSH on the server your want to run the script on
3. Transfer relevant keys to the Windows Server
4. `shell_exec('ssh -i /path/to/private.key -t user@192.168.1.145 "python /path/to/open.py"')`
5. Celebrate!

**Note:** `user` must have the correct permissions

Source(s):

- [Step 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7886229/jbis)
- [Steps 2 & 3](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication)
- [Step 4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119899/267377)
- [Step 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GwjfUFyY6M)

Comment: Hi @Jbis, what is private.key ?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave It is the key that you setup in step 2 and is transferred in step 3.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave See the links in sources.